# How to grant Sharepoint Administrator permission to a list item that has lost access

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint, permissions

I am a Sharepoint Administrator for a website and I created a list of broken permissions at the item level. My ADM user does not have access permission to several of these items, as they were wrongly removed by some users.
Is there any way to grant this permission again to the Administrator? It can be via PowerShell or another way.

How to grant Sharepoint Administrator permission to a list item that has lost access.

I tried running an automate flow to give permission to all items, but an error appears saying I don't have permission to access the item.